# Trying to get at a common php/javascript library with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, apache, mod-rewrite

This is a new understanding of a question I posted previously:

I have a mod_rewrite snippet that finds out whether javascript, css, php files exist on the subdomain where they are called (e.g., `subdomain.example.com`).  If they don't exist, then apache "redirects" to `common.example.com` where common js, css, and php files are.  See below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(js|css|php)$ http://common.example.com/$1.%2 [L]
```

This works if:

- You explicitly plug the requested file name into the address bar.
- It also works if the js or css is referenced/linked in the html markup.

It does not work if

- The url is used inside a php or js file (e.g., for an ajax call).  Instead it references the subdomain where the html page is found (i.e., mod_rewrite doesn't catch it): `subdomain.example.com`

Thanks SO for your help

**EDIT**

Per Pekka's requestion, here is an example:

1. Take for instance *subdomain.example.com/test.html*
2. *test.html* references `<script src="/code/js/test.class.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>`
3. In *test.class.js* there is `$.ajax({ url: "/code/php/test.php", dataType
   : "json", data: {cmd : 'someCommand'}, success: callback()});`

..

- So in #2, it finds `common.example.com/code/js/test.class.js` (Correct!)
- But in #3, the ajax calls on `subdomain.example.com/code/php/test.php` (Incorrect! because of `subdomain`)

Comment: URLs are URLs, no matter where they are referenced. They should always work in the same way. When the subdomain is referenced, the URL should automatically be rewritten. Can you make an example?

Comment: Hi @Pekka! I wrote an example. Hopefully it will help?

Comment: @Emile yeah, I already saw it. So you are saying that the mod_rewrite rules are applied when you reference `subdomain.example.com/code/js/test.class.js` in the browser, but not when you reference a JavaScript in a HTML page?

Comment: @Pekka, It works in both the browser and in the HTML page.  It doesn't work in the javascript file.

Comment: @Emile how do you see that the Ajax request fails (i.e. is not redirected to example.com)?

Comment: Firebug.  It gives me the address with the subdomain, domain, etc.  And "302 Found" message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a side-effect of  <strike>changing thedomain</strike> (as it turned out)  changing the protocol inside the rewrite.

By specifying a full URL in your RewriteRule instead of a filesystem path, you force the server to send a `301` redirect header for every request.

AJAX requests usually [follow header redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325765/jquery-ajax-made-browser-request-new-location-in-redirect-header), *but* you are redirecting to a different domain, thus violating the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)!

This means that for Ajax requests, you can't use this redirection method. You would have to specify a filesystem path in your RewriteRule so the rewrite can take place internally (so that to the browser, it stays `subdomain.example.com/code/php/test.php`). I don't know whether this can be done in your setup.

Comment: Sorry @Pekka for the massive amounts of follow-up, but if that's the case, hard coding the php's full url in the javascript works.  Wouldn't that mean it's a problem with mod_rewrite adn not ajax's same origin policy?   I'll certainly accept this answer, just one more comment :)

Comment: @Emile aaaah, interesting! Then what I say about the Same Origin Policy *might* not apply here because you are redirecting to a top domain of a subdomain. I overlooked that. Then it could be the `302`, I'll check whether I can find anything on that

Comment: @Emile no, the `302` should be interpreted correctly, I don't know what the case is here. What you could try is a different redirect method like `301` or `303`: `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(js|css|php)$ http://common.example.com/$1.%2 [L,R=301]` if that doesn't work out, I don't know what this is. You are not mixing protocols (http / https)?

Comment: I am mixing protocols! oops, was that important to say? :)

Comment: @Emile yup! :)  That probably is what breaks the Same Origin Policy in the redirect. Try a protocol relative URL: `//subdomain.example.com/code/js/test.class.js` (notice the //)

Comment: @Emile ah no, bullshit, a protocol relative URL won't help. The problem is that your RewriteRule always turns the new URL into a HTTP one. You'll have to make it HTTPS aware. I don't know how to do that but this has been discussed on SO, should be possible to find in a search.

Comment: @Awesome, thanks @Pekka for the persistence and good advice!  I will seek HTTPS awareness :)